# Issue with Playing Videos in Full Screen in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have converted our WP 8.0 app to WP 8.1, the application have some video listing, in Windows Phone 8.0 the videos are playing in native video player in Full screen, but after conversion, the videos have started playing inline on the listing screen itself. How can I play those videos using native video player in full screen?

I am using HTML5 with JS for WP development.